# Why does the dielectric constant of a solid increase due to a Frenkel defect?

Tags: crystal-structure, solid-state-chemistry, electricity

In crystalline solids, an atom may be displaced from its original position in order to create a vacancy in the original location. This is referred to as a Frenkel defect. Why does this defect result in an increase of the dielectric constant of the solid?

Comment: I've never truly understood what that even means to be honest. But, given, the only applications of the dielectric constants I've seen are in dissolving polar solvents by water or reducing the electric field inside capacitors ("dielectric substances") I guess this Frenkel defect thing is most probably related to the capacitor part. But, "why" I've no answer.